How to Validate JavaScript and Detect XSS in PDF Files?
I am working on adding JavaScript to a PDF file using the and then validating the presence of JavaScript in the PDF. However, I am having trouble detecting the JavaScript I added. The issue is that the JavaScript code I inserted into the PDF is not being detected by the validation method.
I tried adding JavaScript to a PDF file using the iText library with the following code:
@PostMapping("/addJSInPdf")
public ResponseEntity<String> addJSInPdf(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(inputStream);
        Document document = new Document(reader.getPageSize(1));
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);

        document.open();
        PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfImportedPage importedPage;
        int totalPages = reader.getNumberOfPages();
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
            importedPage = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);
            contentByte.addTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
        }
        writer.addJavaScript("app.alert('This is an alert box in the PDF!');");
        document.close();

        String base64EncodedPdf = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray());
        return ResponseEntity.ok("{\"pdf\":\"" + base64EncodedPdf + "\"}");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return ResponseEntity.status(500).body("{\"error\":\"Internal Server Error\"}");
    }
}


Then, I attempted to validate the presence of JavaScript in the PDF as per following code:
    public boolean validatePDF(byte[] fileContent) {
        try {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent));

            // Check if the PDF contains JavaScript
            if (containsJavaScript(reader)) {
                return true;
            }

            // Additional checks (annotations, AcroForms, etc.) can be added here

            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private boolean containsJavaScript(PdfReader reader) {
        try {
            PdfDictionary catalog = reader.getCatalog();

            // 1. Check OpenAction for JavaScript
            PdfDictionary openAction = catalog.getAsDict(PdfName.OPENACTION);
            if (openAction != null) {
                PdfObject jsObject = openAction.get(PdfName.JS);
                if (jsObject instanceof PdfString) {
                    System.out.println("JavaScript found in OpenAction: " + ((PdfString) jsObject).toUnicodeString());
                    return true;
                }
            }

            // 2. Check additional actions (AA) for JavaScript
            PdfDictionary aa = catalog.getAsDict(PdfName.AA);
            if (aa != null) {
                for (PdfName actionType : aa.getKeys()) {
                    PdfDictionary action = aa.getAsDict(actionType);
                    PdfObject jsObject = action.get(PdfName.JS);
                    if (jsObject instanceof PdfString) {
                        System.out.println(
                                "JavaScript found in Additional Actions: " + ((PdfString) jsObject).toUnicodeString());
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            // 3. Traverse through annotations and actions in all pages
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(i);
                PdfArray annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);
                if (annots != null) {
                    for (PdfObject annotObj : annots) {
                        PdfDictionary annot = (PdfDictionary) PdfReader.getPdfObject(annotObj);
                        PdfObject jsObject = annot.get(PdfName.JS);
                        if (jsObject instanceof PdfString) {
                            System.out.println(
                                    "JavaScript found in Annotation: " + ((PdfString) jsObject).toUnicodeString());
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // 4. Check the Names dictionary for JavaScript
            PdfDictionary names = catalog.getAsDict(PdfName.NAMES);
            if (names != null) {
                PdfDictionary embeddedJS = names.getAsDict(PdfName.JAVASCRIPT);
                if (embeddedJS != null) {
                    PdfArray jsArray = embeddedJS.getAsArray(PdfName.NAMES);
                    if (jsArray != null) {
                        for (int i = 1; i < jsArray.size(); i += 2) {
                            PdfObject jsObject = jsArray.getDirectObject(i);
                            if (jsObject instanceof PdfString) {
                                System.out.println(
                                        "JavaScript found in Names: " + ((PdfString) jsObject).toUnicodeString());
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }


I'm working on a method to validate whether a PDF contains embedded JavaScript. I expected the validation method to correctly detect the JavaScript in the PDF, but it’s not working as intended.
Could anyone provide guidance on:
1.Proper dependencies required for validating JavaScript in PDFs?
2.Example code for detecting embedded JavaScript in PDFs?
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Your so-called PDFBox code isn't. Likely itext.

@Tilman  "Likely itext." - indeed, and considering the patterns used, it's an old text version (5.x or earlier).

@Ravi your iText based code to check the JavaScript name tree is highly deficient. You should re-read the PDF specification and fix your code.

which library is best for find javascript code in pdf file ?

Unless you find a library that offers extraction of all JS as an explicit API part (which I don't know of; but I really don't know all PDF libraries, so maybe there is), any general purpose PDF library can serve as base upon which you implement the methods.
